# What happens when Core Cluster Group is failed over to another node? Will it take the whole cluster down? Single point of failure?

Tags: sql-server, windows-server-2012-r2, failovercluster, sql-server-2012, windows-cluster

http://bit.ly/1lKJFIa "Cluster group" fail-over will cause cluster go offline. Really? Single point of failure? Am I missing something? What happens when Core Cluster resources (Cluster Group) are failed over from one node to another? Will it take whole cluster down? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if any of the resources in the Cluster Group fail, the cluster will go offline.

No, it is not a single point of failure. The Cluster Name, and IP address are responded to by all nodes in a cluster. If multiple nodes go down, the remaining nodes will attempt to form a quorum and continue responding to requests.

The Quorum resource is only needed when a cluster has an even number of nodes. It is usually the witness disk and is given a tiebreaker vote for quorum. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731739.aspx